# During an aborted deployment, some instances may have deployed the new application version

Tags: asp.net, amazon-web-services

I am trying to deploy ASP.NET application to AWS. When I press deploy button I get error

> During an aborted deployment, some instances may have deployed the new application version. To ensure all instances are running the same version, re-deploy the appropriate application version.

I have no idea where I made mistake and what's going wrong
Any comment ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can get this error message if you're trying to deploy source file zip with same name which is already deployed. **ZIP FILE NAME not TAG !!!**.

You should always deploy source file zip with different name.

Best practice is use version number which is increasing (eg. Project-v2) or something else.

Comment: what if you are doing this through code pipeline from GitHub as source?

Comment: if you are using code pipeline you probably pull your source from your repository instead of upload zip file so this WHAT IF is really pointless IMHO

Comment: @daremachine I have tried multiple times with different names of my source code bundle but still I am facing same error.

Comment: @AmitShakya if your package is on server then try upload any other, delete old from backup and then upload new

Comment: That didn't help in my situation.

Comment: what if i'm doing this from the eb console

Answer (score 11):

@user2763557 
I know the question is quite old, but I had a similiar issue trying to deploy my code **from Github via Code Pipeline.**

But I solved the problem. It was an error, which happened when composer tried to install PHP version 7.3 while I was running 7.4 on the Elastic Beanstalk.

 So a good way to solve other similiar problems is to download the **full logs** in Elastic Beanstalk and open **eb-engine.log** and look for similiar errors like mine:

> Problem 1
>      - This package requires php 7.3.* but your PHP version (7.4.4) does not satisfy that >requirement. 
>   2020/05/08 12:38:42.162732 [INFO] Executing cleanup logic 
>  
>   2020/05/08 12:38:42.162814 [INFO] CommandService Response:{"status":"FAILURE","api_version":"1.0","results":[{"status":"FAILURE","msg":"Engine >execution has encountered an error.","returncode":1,"events":[]}]}

That was my error, which **stopped** the **Code Pipeline Deployment process** and threw the error.
I hope that can help someone.

Comment: @Chanchal Raj I changed my PHP Version in my composer.json to 7.4. So next time when I deployed my project, composer installed 7.4 which now matched my Elastic Beanstalk PHP version.

Answer (score 4):

in my case, it's bug of `Microsoft.Powershell.Archive`.

https://superuser.com/questions/1382839/zip-files-expand-with-backslashes-on-linux-no-subdirectories

I find these message from log file:`/var/log/eb-engine.log`

```
An error occurred during execution of command [app-deploy] - [StageJavaApplication]. Stop running the command. Error: Command /bin/sh -c /usr/bin/unzip -q -o /opt/elasticbeanstalk/deployment/app_source_bundle -d /tmp/extracted_app_source_bundle failed with error exit status 1. Stderr:warning:  /opt/elasticbeanstalk/deployment/app_source_bundle appears to use backslashes as path separators
```

I can deploy successfully zip file - that archived by other program.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I got this error using **Code Pipeline** and **GitHub** to deploy **Node.js**:

```
2020-12-28 14:39:30 UTC+0900    
ERROR
During an aborted deployment, some instances may have deployed the new application version. To ensure all instances are running the same version, re-deploy the appropriate application version.
2020-12-28 14:39:29 UTC+0900    
ERROR
Failed to deploy application.
2020-12-28 14:39:29 UTC+0900    
ERROR
Encountered AccessDeniedException: User: ..... is not authorized to perform: logs:DescribeLogGroups on resource: arn:aws:logs:ap-northeast-2:...
```

eventho I got the error the server was updated, so I add the permission for code pipeline to see logs and everything worked fine

to fix that I did:

1. **IAM**
2. **Roles**
3. **Selected the code pipeline rule**
4. **Add AWSElasticBeanstalkFullAccess policy**

Comment: What option is this? < Selected the code pipeline rule>sorry for my ignorance!

Answer (score 2):

I know that this is an old question posted, but the problem may never be old because it might recur due to several issues.
I faced the same issue when I was hosting my HTML based website using Docker containers.

I fixed it, by exposing the port number

Previously it was:

```
From nginx

WORKDIR '/app'

COPY ./html/ /usr/share/nginx/html/
```

This worked locally but failed during deployment on AWS Elasticbeanstalk.

I downloaded the logs and perceived that the problem might be due to not exposing the port of nginx server. So I exposed port 80, the default nginx server, and deployed it again on AWS Elasticbeanstalk.

Now this time, it works!

The Dockerfile which helped in successful deployment was as follows:

```
From nginx

EXPOSE 80

WORKDIR '/app'

COPY ./html/ /usr/share/nginx/html/
```

Answer (score 1):

Try including package-lock.json in your zip or github repo if using codepipeline

Answer (score 1):

just delete all application version from your elastic beanstalk environment

Go to environment -> in sidebar select application versions under application: {application name}
than select all versions and delete all.

Answer (score 0):

in my case, i was trying to deploy from EBS Cli, ¿what i did to fix it?, Just remove the last versions from AWS Console, and upload again an new version of my app, and then this works good.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error. I checked the eb engine logs and had different versions of the same package in requirements. Eg:

```
flask-socketio==5.3.2
flask-socketio==5.3.1
```

After deleting one of them deployment went successfully.

Answer (score 0):

I followed [NKol's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61680047) and they basically nailed the reason. I was running Django app on AWS and I had a Code pipeline Via GitHub. This is what it said in the eb-engine.log

```
2023/02/09 01:26:59.890761 [INFO] Starting...
2023/02/09 01:26:59.890810 [INFO] Starting EBPlatform-PlatformEngine
2023/02/09 01:26:59.890827 [INFO] reading event message file
2023/02/09 01:26:59.890947 [INFO] Engine received EB command cfn-hup-exec

2023/02/09 01:26:59.954386 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c /opt/aws/bin/cfn-get-metadata -s arn:aws:cloudformation:eu-central-1:429834728703:stack/awseb-e-jaqzdwbxa3-stack/012e7840-1654-11ed-bd87-06a5d714e8d0 -r AWSEBAutoScalingGroup --region eu-central-1
2023/02/09 01:27:00.316934 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c /opt/aws/bin/cfn-get-metadata -s arn:aws:cloudformation:eu-central-1:429834728703:stack/awseb-e-jaqzdwbxa3-stack/012e7840-1654-11ed-bd87-06a5d714e8d0 -r AWSEBBeanstalkMetadata --region eu-central-1
2023/02/09 01:27:00.618725 [INFO] checking whether command app-deploy is applicable to this instance...
2023/02/09 01:27:00.618741 [INFO] this command is not applicable to the instance, thus instance shouldn't execute command
2023/02/09 01:27:00.618744 [INFO] skip command app-deploy for this instance...
2023/02/09 01:27:00.618753 [ERROR] Ignoring not applicable command.
2023/02/09 01:27:00.618756 [INFO] Executing cleanup logic
2023/02/09 01:27:00.618825 [INFO] CommandService Response: {"status":"FAILURE","api_version":"1.0","results":[{"status":"FAILURE","msg":"Ignoring not applicable command.","returncode":0,"events":[]}]}

2023/02/09 01:27:00.618985 [INFO] Platform Engine finished execution on command: app-deploy
```

Basically, on my local server, I was running python 3.10 and in the code, I used the new Switches(Match Case), but on the server, the python version was 3.7 which did not have Switches. This is why we should use docker.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, once, I deployed a `rar` instead of the `zip` version.

I'm not 100% sure (I would be happy if someone can confirm), but I probably had this issue once again, when I created my project with `Elastic Beanstalk` where I set a timezone to *Paris*. When - later - I was attaching my **DB** with `RDS` I had forgotten to set a proper zone. By default, it was set to **Ohio**. Because of that, firstly, I surprisingly realized that my **DB - RDS ** disappeared (because in meantime I change the timezone to **Paris** again). Having a different timezone than that one set for a particular `DB`/`project` **makes your files invisible**. Till now I don't know why **AWS** is constructed in such a way. Anyway, maybe this also caused aborted deployment, because the `DATABASES_HOST` has the timezone as a part of the string.

For example: django-coolproject-python-db.cyjfooi5barh5.**eu-west-3**.rds.amazonaws.com

Answer (score 0):

In my case, updating my node version to 19 in Dockerfile did the trick.