# ERROR: During an aborted deployment, some instances may have deployed the new application version

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

ERROR: During an aborted deployment, some instances may have deployed the new application version. To ensure all instances are running the same version, re-deploy the appropriate application version.

Error Screenshot:
[image: Screenshot 1]

Comment: if you deploy with zip file, then check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51155927/during-an-aborted-deployment-some-instances-may-have-deployed-the-new-applicati/62906905#62906905)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try anything to resolve it? It can be fixed by Rebooting the instance in EC2.

Comment: It can be many things. The most recommended is to read the log "eb-engine.log". In my case for example the error was "Error: there is no Procfile and no .jar file at root level of your source bundle". I was deploying the JAR inside the target folder and not at root level.